# What can I do about my original 3DS D-pad down arrow being stuck?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Recently, when I press the down button on my original 3DS D-pad, it becomes stuck and continues registering presses. It only becomes stuck when that key is pressed meaning that prior to pressing the key, everything works normally. I have reset the console twice to no avail (obviously not a software problem). I have dismantled the console and examined the button but I see nothing unusual. What is your advice to rectifying this problem?

Comment: Could you upload a photo of the button?

Comment: @RoijanEskor I assume the button contact with the console dismantled? Unfortunately, I reassembled the console earlier.

Comment: Is the button physically sticking or is it just constantly registering presses?

Comment: Are there little rubber pads behind the D-Pad buttons?  I know I've run into the problem of those wearing out on guitar hero controllers and then running into sticking problems.